# What is the best method to bring a gigantic JS object to client side?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best method to bring a gigantic JS object to client side?

Comment: To be even more precise than you: that depends.

Comment: No @Robert, it depends does not apply here. Having a _gigantic JS object_ on the client side is never a good idea

Comment: @baao: I don't think so. Having as much info on the client side as possible/reasonable can make a huge difference in terms of performance and UE as it can drastically reduce roundtrips to the server/database etc. The thing is to to get the relevant data from server to client without blocking or slowing down things. And how to specifically do that: *it depends* (on the actual structure and data layout) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good idea. You are going to bloat your website / application size and it will run very slowly.

You are better off putting that object either into a database or at least server side in some form and making API calls to just the data you need, when you need it.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You should probably request smaller partions  ( via ajax ), and from there. We don't have any context to what OP is going to use his object for though.